# Using rxjava to get bitmap for every list item

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I'm using Retrofit to get data from REST service. After recive json (list of objects) I want to get a bitmap for every position on the list. What is the best way to do this? I'm trying to use map/flat map on my Observable created by Retrofit, but It's not works (or, propably, I'm doing it wrong).

**Retrofit interface method:**

```
@POST("links/promoted/appkey/{appkey}/page/{page}/sort/{sort}")
public Observable<List<Link>> promoted(@Path("appkey") String appkey,
                                       @Path("page") int page,
                                       @Path("sort") String sort);
```

**Usage:**

```
linksService
        .promoted(Extras.APP_KEY, page, Sort.DAY)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .subscribe(links -> {
            view.appendLinks(links);
        });
```

When I'm trying to use flatMap() or map() it's always return a list, but i need every item separately.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
linksService
    .promoted(Extras.APP_KEY, page, Sort.DAY)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .flatMapIterable(list -> list)
    .subscribe(link -> {
        view.appendLinks(link);
    });
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!